# How to Prevent onblur code to execute& DISABLE (Stop form from submitting normally)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Cannot disable onclick/onblur values[Click to see the problem in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKn24.png)

```
  name="otp" id="otp" size="50" maxlength="6" value="" onblur="encrypt_otp($(this).val());" type="password"
```

//code of HTML

```
    <script>
        function encrypt_otp(otp_var) {
        // Stop form from submitting normally             

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "json/encryptData",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {otp :otp_var},
            success: function (data) {                    
                $('#otp').val(data['encrypted_value']);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        })
                .done(function (data) {
                })
                .fail(function () {

                })
                .always(function () {
                });
    }
     </script>
```

is it possible to solve through preventDefault();/return value;
or how can i solve this..

Comment: You fill input with server returned text `$('#otp').val(data['encrypted_value']);` I dont understand what the problem is - `maxlength` is ignored because you fill input by js

Comment: i wanna bypass encryption...or disabling encryption
(cause encrypted_value is giving result "invalid")

Comment: simply remove onblur attribute and it won't encrypt value )

Comment: i have tried this before but it's giving the same result "invalid otp"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `autocomplete="off"` on you input field.

[description](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)